# qgis2web not working with style file

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

`qgis2web` is working well with the default styles

[image]

However when a `style file` is used the `qgis2web` preview does not load,

[image]

Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you describe the symbology within this style file?  SVG symbols, graduated, categorized?  Or even provide the style file?

Comment: Yes it is SVG symbols

Answer (score 1):

This happens because qgis2web does not support some specific aspect of your QGIS style. The preview window is blank because a Javascript error prevents the webpage from rendering. Instructions for how to debug this and submit a useful bug report are on the qgis2web issue tracker here: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues. @GreyHippo is right: you need to supply your QML or project file (with the layer to which it applies) in order to debug the problem further.